# How to convert multiple time zone column to UTC in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, timezone

I have a dataset where the date_time column contains a mixture of BST and GMT date and times, in the following format 'Sun 27 Mar 2022 12:59:03 AM GMT'. I would like to convert this whole column into the following format '2022-03-27 00:59:03', and into one standard time zone, such as UTC. Where am I going wrong??

I tried using strptime() to convert the a tester date, but that only works with GMT times.

```
date_time_str = 'Sun 27 Mar 2022 12:59:03 AM GMT'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z')
print('Date-time:', date_time_obj)
```

> Date-time: 2022-03-27 00:59:03

Then tried with BST

```
date_time_str_bst = 'Sun 27 Mar 2022 02:00:02 AM BST'
date_time_obj_bst = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str_bst, '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z')
```

> ValueError: time data 'Sun 27 Mar 2022 02:00:02 AM BST' does not match format '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z'

[image]

Comment: The '%Z' format works for a system time zone and UTC/GMT. So you have to parse the time zone by yourself. And I don't know a library that parses a DST zone, such as BST.

Comment: do you handle this data in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @relent95 in fact, no library *should* parse abbreviated tz names such as "BST" - not because of DST but because of ambiguity. There are at least [3 BST timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations). OP will have to *define* to which tz the abbreviations maps; e.g. "Europe/London".

Comment: @FObersteiner - yes it is handled in pandas dataframe. How would you go about defining tz of every row in a column, so they are all standardised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option how you can handle this. As commented, abbreviated tz names such as "BST" are ambiguous. You will have to define to which tz the abbreviations map; e.g. "Europe/London" for BST/GMT.

**define timezone mapping {abbreviation --> IANA tz name}, apply parser, then convert to UTC**

given

```
df
                     Date and time  temp
0  Sun 27 Mar 2022 12:57:03 AM GMT  33.9
1  Sun 27 Mar 2022 12:58:02 AM GMT  33.6
2  Sun 27 Mar 2022 12:59:03 AM GMT  33.6
3  Sun 27 Mar 2022 02:00:02 AM BST  33.9
4  Sun 27 Mar 2022 02:01:03 AM BST  33.6
5  Sun 27 Mar 2022 02:02:02 AM BST  33.6
```

running

```py
import pandas as pd
import dateutil

tzmapping = {"GMT": dateutil.tz.gettz("Europe/London"),
             "BST": dateutil.tz.gettz("Europe/London")}

df["dt_UTC"] = df["Date and time"].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, tzinfos=tzmapping).dt.tz_convert("UTC")
```

gives

```
df
                     Date and time  temp                    dt_UTC
0  Sun 27 Mar 2022 12:57:03 AM GMT  33.9 2022-03-27 00:57:03+00:00
1  Sun 27 Mar 2022 12:58:02 AM GMT  33.6 2022-03-27 00:58:02+00:00
2  Sun 27 Mar 2022 12:59:03 AM GMT  33.6 2022-03-27 00:59:03+00:00
3  Sun 27 Mar 2022 02:00:02 AM BST  33.9 2022-03-27 01:00:02+00:00
4  Sun 27 Mar 2022 02:01:03 AM BST  33.6 2022-03-27 01:01:03+00:00
5  Sun 27 Mar 2022 02:02:02 AM BST  33.6 2022-03-27 01:02:02+00:00
```

Comment: Thank you @FObersteiner for helping me. I tried method 1, and ran it through my column of dates, but I got an error message for when the time changes later in the year (Sun 30 Oct 2022 01:59:02 AM BST, Sun 30 Oct 2022 01:00:03 GMT). The error message is: AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from 2022-10-30 01:00:02, try using the 'ambiguous' argument

Comment: Method 2, again I am getting an error message TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not float

Comment: @U108456 ok, definitely use method #2 then. I forgot to mention the DST issue. Regarding the error, did you copy&paste my synthetic example and made sure it works? Did you make sure all the column elements you want to convert are of type string?

Comment: I tried method 2 as you have written and it works. However when I put the column in (pandas column, dtype: object), it gives me the same error message, but there is no float in my data when I checked

Comment: `data = pd.read_csv("XXX.csv")`

Comment: `data["input"] = data["Date and time"]`

Comment: `tzmapping = {"GMT": tz.gettz("Europe/London"),
             "BST": tz.gettz("Europe/London")}`

Comment: `data["datetime"] = data["input"].apply(parser.parse, tzinfos=tzmapping).dt.tz_convert("UTC")`

Comment: @U108456 hm that's weird, can you add exemplary content of `data["Date and time"]` to the question, + the error traceback?

Comment: I think I have managed to add some content of the column, I added another column to give an example of my data but that is relevant for this task. There is an image attached of the error too.

Comment: @U108456 I've updated the answer to include your example data. However I fear I cannot reproduce the issue, without seeing your actual input...

Comment: your solution actually worked. Schoolboy error for not removing 'NaN's first! thanks